# Given transposed=1, weight of size [1024, 512, 2, 2], expected input[5, 1536, 20, 20] to have 1024 channels, but got 1536 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to implement UNET from scratch using this image.
[image]

This is my code:

```
class DoubleConv2D(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
    super(DoubleConv2D, self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels # 3
    self.out_channels = out_channels # 1
    self.conv2d = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels, self.out_channels, 3, 1, 1, bias=False), # padding = 1 = same convolution = in h,w will be same after conv operation
        nn.BatchNorm2d(self.out_channels),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(self.out_channels, self.out_channels, 3, 1, 1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(self.out_channels),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  def forward(self, x):
    return self.conv2d(x)

class UNET(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_channels=3, out_channels=1, filters=[64, 128, 256, 512]):
    super(UNET, self).__init__()
    self.in_channels = in_channels
    self.out_channels = out_channels
    self.filters = filters
    
    self.up_sample_layers = nn.ModuleList()
    self.down_sample_layers = nn.ModuleList()
    self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    
    # downsampling
    for filter_channel in self.filters:
      self.down_sample_layers.append(DoubleConv2D(self.in_channels, filter_channel)) # 3 to 64
      self.in_channels = filter_channel # 3 = 64

    self.bottleneck = DoubleConv2D(self.filters[-1], self.filters[-1]*2)

    # upsampling
    for filter_channel in reversed(self.filters):
      self.up_sample_layers.append(nn.ConvTranspose2d(filter_channel*2, filter_channel, kernel_size=2, stride=2))
      self.up_sample_layers.append(DoubleConv2D(filter_channel*2, filter_channel))

    self.final_conv = nn.Conv2d(self.filters[0], self.out_channels, kernel_size=1)

  def forward(self, x):
    skip_connections = []
    
    # downsampling
    for down_sampling_layer in self.down_sample_layers:
      x = down_sampling_layer(x)
      # save skip connection for later use before applying max pool layer
      skip_connections.append(x)
      x = self.maxpool(x)
    
    x = self.bottleneck(x)

    # reversing skip connections list because we need to go in opposite direction
    skip_connections = skip_connections[::-1]
    print([t.shape for t in skip_connections])

    # upsampling
    for index, up_sampling_layer in enumerate(self.up_sample_layers):
      if index%2==0: 
        x = up_sampling_layer(x)
      else: 
        skip_connection = skip_connections[index]
        if x.shape != skip_connection.shape:
          x = F.resize(x, size=skip_connection.shape[2:])
        print(x.shape)
        print(skip_connection.shape)
        concat = torch.cat((skip_connection, x), dim=1) # dim=1 = channels, (batch, c, h, w)
        #ERROR
        x = up_sampling_layer(concat)
    
    return self.final_conv(x)
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:718: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)

[torch.Size([5, 512, 20, 20]), torch.Size([5, 256, 40, 40]), torch.Size([5, 128, 80, 80]), torch.Size([5, 64, 160, 160])]
torch.Size([5, 512, 40, 40])
torch.Size([5, 256, 40, 40])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-6-ceca97b4e23f> in <module>()
      2 input_sample = torch.randn((5, 3, 160, 160)) # batch, channels, height, width
      3 model = UNET(in_channels=3, out_channels=1)
----> 4 predictions = model(input_sample)
      5 print(input_sample.shape)
      6 print(predictions.shape)

8 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-5-7f40e2734019> in forward(self, x)
     52         concat = torch.cat((skip_connection, x), dim=1) # dim=1 = channels, (batch, c, h, w)
     53         #ERROR
---> 54         x = up_sampling_layer(concat)
     55 
     56     return self.final_conv(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-4-12aa7dca95ac> in forward(self, x)
     13     )
     14   def forward(self, x):
---> 15     return self.conv2d(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    137     def forward(self, input):
    138         for module in self:
--> 139             input = module(input)
    140         return input
    141 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1049         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1050                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1051             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1052         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1053         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    441 
    442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 443         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    444 
    445 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    438                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    439         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 440                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    441 
    442     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [512, 1024, 3, 3], expected input[5, 768, 40, 40] to have 1024 channels, but got 768 channels instead
```

The filter values are not matching somehow, there are 4 skip connections with channels -> 64, 128, 256 and 512, but to concatinate it should have been 1024 I guess?
I am not able to see what's wrong, if anyone could help, it would be really great!

EDIT : UPDATED THE ERROR AND CONDITION `if index%2==0`.

Comment: The problem is the if statement (if index%2). For the 0th upsampling layer the condition is negative such that the upsampling layer is not applied to x and therefore has the wrong number of channels. Setting the condition to if index%2==0 should fix the problem

Comment: @NiklasHöpner Hi thanks for replying, I got another error after doing what you suggested: `Given groups=1, weight of size [512, 1024, 3, 3], expected input[5, 768, 40, 40] to have 1024 channels, but got 768 channels instead` on line `x = up_sampling_layer(concat)`.

Comment: Successfully solved the error. My up_sample_layers were of length 8 and skip_connections had 4 elements, so that was the main problem. So to resolve the error I declared a variable specially for `skip_connections` and whenever the `else` executes, I incremented by 1 so that it sequentially iterates over the skip connections.